# Saving multiple values from a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIViewController which calls 4 UITableViewControllers as its subview.

These tableview has accessory checkmark enabled and can select multiple rows in a table.

My question is when my UIViewController is displayed with all the tableview, I want to save the selected values of each tableview and save it in an array or something else.

I also want to use these selected values in another class, where I have to display all these selected values.

Can anyone help me out with this on how to save multiple values of different tableview and use those values in another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `indexPathsForSelectedRows`.
But this instruction will return more than one `indexPath`.

That said, Xcode has a brilliant autocompletion feature, you could have started to type "index" and it would have shown `indexPathsForSelectedRows` directly, you can also refer to the excellent documentation provided with Xcode. I Hope it will help you!

**UPDATE 1 - How to grab the indexPaths from the array**

the `indexPathsForSelectedRows` method will return an array of NSIndexPath objects, each of which corresponds to a single selected item. If there are no selected items, this method returns an empty array.

Now to access this object, you have to ask yourself, how do I access an array? You do some research and then you will come to this conclusion:

```
NSArray *arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne = [self.myTableViewOne indexPathsForSelectedRows];

//Then you can iterate through the array and doWhatever you like. 
for(int i = 0; i < [arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne count]; i++){
    NSIndexPath *indexPathImInterestedIn = [arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne objectAtIndex:i];
    //If you do actually have a tableViewController then call [self cellFor...]; instead of self.myTableViewOne 
    UITableViewCell *currentCell = [self.myTableViewOne cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathImInterestedIn];

    //you can grab the data you need from this cell and do whatever you like
    //I would suggest you grab the data from the datasource instead of the cell, since your datasource should contain the datamodel where you can extract the information you need.

    //Or if its just one value from the cell you want to grab you could do
    [myGlobalArray addObject:[NSString stringWithObject:@"%@", currentCell.textLabel.text]]; //your value
}

//Voila
```

Comment: The OP has a view controller that contains several Table View **Controllers**, not table views. Thus your ‘self.myTableViewOne’ code won't work. (And manipulating another view controllers view hierarchy breaks the encapsulation of the other VC.) That's why I suggested creating a protocol to communicate between view controllers.

Comment: I doubt he has 4 `UITableViewControllers` in his `UIViewController` and instead has `UITableViews` that he's created.  I remember in my day when I used to call UITableViews UITableViewControllers. But it's no problem, the OP can simply do `self` right followed by the method he wishes to invoke. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

How are you hosting these table view controllers in your parent view controller? If you're using storyboards, the cleanest way to do this is to use an embed segue.

Then, in prepareForSegue, you can save pointers to each of your child table view controllers.

I would suggest designing a protocol that would let the parent view controller ask the child table view controller for it's list of selected items. Alternately you could set up the parent view controller as a delegate of each of the table view controllers, and create delegate methods that notify the parent when the user changes the currently selected item.

I have a sample project on github that has a parent view controller hosting 2 table view controllers where both the parent and child view controllers use protocols to communicate with each other. Check it out by clicking this link

[**Demo project using embed segues to manage multiple static table views**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/test)

Note that for a single table view, the method indexPathsForSelectedRows will return an array of all the selected items in the table view.

Comment: @duncan_c I know this SO post is complete now, but do reread his question again, the OP stated "I want to save the selected values of each tableview and save it in an array or something else". Your answer has nothing to do with what the OP is having problems with. Just thought id give you a heads up before you get down voted or something. Ciao

Comment: @Pavan, if you read the OPs entire post, it's pretty clear that he/she is asking how to pass info about selected cells from a table view controller up to it's parent.

Comment: @duncan_c Aha you're absoluty right, sorry. Towards the end he asks that, so we both answered different questions in his post. We should combine our answer ;) Have a good day