# Capturing multiple values from UITableView with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to use a uitableview as a picker to allow the user to make multiple selections. I've set the tableview up to allow this and my coreData has a one-to-many relationship to allow for multiple values. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to capture the selected rows as values in my coreData.

I populate the table by fetching data from my 'Players' entity and storing it in this variable:

```
var playerPickerData = [NSManagedObject]()
```

I am guessing that I need to do something with the `selectedrowsatindexpaths` function to then extract the values back out of `playerPickerData` to be able to then add them to my 'Match' entity (which is linked to my players entity with a one-to-many relationship).

The code I have to populate my table cells is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = playersPicker.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    let fName = playerPickerData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "firstName") as! String

    let lName = playerPickerData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "lastName") as! String

    let playersNameData = "\(fName) \(lName)"

    cell.textLabel?.text = playersNameData

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath as NSIndexPath)
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

I have a UIPickerView that is used to select one value ('Game Name') and I can capture what I need to from this without issue by using the following on my SavePressed function:

```
let newMatch = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Match", into: context)

let selectedGame = pickerData[gamePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    newMatch.setValue(selectedGame, forKey: "game")
```

**I just need to know how i can save multiple values forKey = "players".** Any advice on how/where to do this in my code would be very much appreciated.

If I can provide any more information then please let me know.

I genuinely cannot find anything that answers these questions here or elsewhere online. I think this might relate but I cannot translate it to my needs: [Saving multiple values from a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314197/saving-multiple-values-from-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just need to know how i can save multiple values forKey = "players".

Always read the documentation of methods you are using when questions arise. The documentation of `NSManagedObject.setValue(:forKey:)` states:

> If key identifies a to-one relationship, relates the object specified by value to the receiver, unrelating the previously related object if there was one. Given a collection object and a key that identifies a to-many relationship, relates the objects contained in the collection to the receiver, unrelating previously related objects if there were any.

So as long as you can construct and maintain a `Set` (Core Data uses sets to store to-many relationships) of your selected `NSManagedObject`s, you can simply do something along the lines of:

```
selectedObjects = [NSManagedObject]() // Fill this Array
parent.setValue(Set(selectedObjects), forKey: "key")
```

and it will automatically reset the to-many relationship, adding any new items and subtracting any that are not contained in the new collection.

It looks like you are maintaining a `selectedIndexPaths` array. In that case, you could do:

```
selectedIndexPaths.map { playerPickerData[$0.row] }
```

to get the selected objects, assuming your table view has a single section. You'll then need to turn that into a `Set` as displayed above. You could also collect the selected index paths as a set in the first place, but then after you map it it will be an `Array` again anyway.

### PS

Note that in your `didSelectRow` you add the selected index paths to `selectedIndexPaths`, but you never remove them from `selectedIndexPaths` in `didDeselectRow`.

Comment: ok - that populated my array fine (thank you) but throws an exception at runtime as it says the one-to-many relationship requires an NSSet. Error: Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "players"; desired type = NSSet. Any advice?

Comment: I apologize. I had assumed Arrays would work because of the wording of the documentation, but pparently not. I updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for your help Matthew. Really appreciated.